# PHP Apache mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, wamp

Here's the basic information:
I'm using WAMP on Windows 8 64 bit. Apache 2.4.2, PHP 5.4+.

My project files are located in `http://localhost/test/`.
The `.htaccess` file in this folder is:

```
RewriteEngine on

#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

If I enter a URL like `http://localhost/test/some/cool/stuff/`, it works fine

i.e. in PHP: `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = index.php&some/cool/stuff/`
I wish it stripped the `index.php&` as well but I'm doing that in PHP.

While if I enter a URL like `http://localhost/test/some/cool/stuff`
the PHP `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` returns `index.php&some/cool/stuff/&some/cool/stuff`

Where's this `&some/cool/stuff/` part coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use `RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php [L]`
And then get the URL by `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

I use this function for PHP to get the request URL with fallback.

```
private static function get_request_URL() {
    if (isset($_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"])) {
        $realURL = $_SERVER["REDIRECT_URL"];
    } elseif (isset($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"])) {
        list($realURL) = explode("?", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    $realURL = rtrim(trim(strtolower($realURL)), "/");
    if ($realURL == "") {
        $realURL = "/";
    }
    return $realURL;
}
```